# How to do this computation-heavy query on millions of rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using Idempotence to make sure the same Message doesn't get saved to the DB more than once. To ensure this, I need a combination of 3 columns. Instead of indexing on 3 columns where one might be null, I instead do a calculation and Digest and store that on a column that is indexed and unique.

I now need to apply this calculation to all previous messages, for which there are millions of rows.

Message.rb:

```
 def set_unique_identifier
    part_one   = mm_id || SecureRandom.uuid
    part_two   = c_id
    part_three = s_id
    self.unique_identifier = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{part_one}-#{part_two}-#{part_three}")
  end
```

and then I have a migration like so:

```
Message.find_each.with_index do |message, index|
  message.set_unique_identifier
  message.save
  puts "SETTING UNIQUE IDENTIFIER FOR #{index}" if index % 1000 == 0
end
```

however, obviously, this is going to take a really long time to compute. is there a faster way to do this using raw SQL?

Comment: Why do you need `unique_identifier` at all? Why can't you make a unique constraint/index on three columns?

Comment: @muistooshort mm_id might be nil, but I want that to still be unique. I could have a partial index (where mm_id != nil) but i figured indexing on 3 columns would be more taxing long term on the db than using a single column and doing a migration now. am I misinformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're going to have a certain level of computation involved no matter what the solution with a million rows.   What you can do is reduce the movement of data.  Postgresql's encrypt module has support for SHA1 hashing and UUID generation.

Using those you can use keep the logic in the server and execute it as single SQL statement, or multiple statements if you want to do it in chunks.

```
UPDATE message SET unique_identifier = encode(digest(
mm_id || gen_random_uuid() || '-' || c_id || '-' || s_id
,'sha1'),'hex');
```

However, what you're doing won't actually check for uniqueness because the random component means that two messages with same mm_id,c_id,s_id could be allowed.

You'd be best off using a unique database constraint.  You can either create a unique index on the raw columns.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON message(mm_id,c_id,s_id);
```

and rely on postgres to handle that.  This is what I'd do first and not worry about performance issues until you've tried it that way and can measure performance.

An alternative is to create an index on a function.  It will operate in about the same way:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON message (encode(digest(mm_id || c_id || s_id,'sha1'),'hex'));
```

Comment: that makes sense. where would i put this code? in a migration on the db?

Comment: edited my answer, because i realised the random bit is going to prevent uniqueness checks from working

Comment: one thing that makes it a bit more difficult is that i only want a unique constraint if mm_id is not nil. so if there are two rows with mm_id = nil, c_id = x, and s_id = x, that should still be unique. that's why i have part_one   = mm_id || SecureRandom.uuid in the set_unique_identifier method

Comment: Can resolve that by adding a clause to the unique index. 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON message(mm_id,c_id,s_id) WHERE mm_id IS NOT NULL

Comment: I read somewhere that add_index unique: true doesn't count NULL values by default. do you know if that is true?